# HowTo use https with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl

I'am trying to configure apache to use a Self signed certificate to Secure https connections.

This is working Fine using only One domainname.

But how do i configure this to Support the Different hostnames  our Server can be reached?

I've tried to create a multidomain cert, but with this cert the authentification of Single Domain does Not Even work.

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at creating a `SAN` - subject alternative name - which is essentially extending your certificate to cover aliases to your server. You'll need to regenerate the certificate to do this.

Comment: I've already done this. But entering the ip Adress result in an ssl error.

Comment: Entering the IP Address certainly gives you an ssl error, if you haven't included it in your cert as a name

Comment: I've now added the ip adress with the dns Syntax. It's working now, i've added the ip adress with the ip flag before.